# How to generate XML sitemap for php website

Tags: php, sitemap

Since now we have used wordpress for our website, and the xml sitemap was very easy to create for the whole website with some plugins.
Now we are switching to a php website created from scratch, after some google search i haven't found something to help me to understand how can i create a sitemap for my website .

Please can some one help, with any kind of software or any web script?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on how your web site is structured. Is it based on a CMS?

Comment: the cms is wordpress, but the website that visitors see, is all created with php.

Comment: It isn't actually clear to me if you need help getting a list of all pages, or processing that list to a sitemap. These are two different steps to me.

Comment: i need both of them, i need to create a sitemap. for google, yahoo, bing etc

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you have the pages served (from database, include files, what-have-you) but, if you don't have very many pages you could simply create a document called `sitemap.xml` by hand and place it in your root directory. There are droves of examples you could emulate from a quick google search.

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to at least get all 75,000 addresses into an array? Also, what does your `.htaccess` file look like?

Comment: hello, i dont know how to  create a sitemap, i have ussed wordpress sitemap generator till now.

Comment: I get that, but to auto-generate a sitemap, you're going to need the addresses you'll be building it with.

Answer (score 0):

To create a sitemap.xml, read up on [sitemap.xml format](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php), then create an XML file that conforms to that format.

How to do this? Well, that depends on the structure of your site. Maybe you could write it by hand, maybe you could generate it based on stuff in the database, maybe you could crawl your site, maybe you could...? This question doesn't really have a specific answer--it all depends on how your site is organized.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of pages in a database, you can use that. Almost all websites have either a directory of static pages, a database with pages, or a combination of both. You should be able to generate a list of all your pages. If you can put them in an array, you can put them in XML as well. Use the SimpleXML extension from PHP. It is, well, Simple. :)

If you cannot generate an export this way, you could use some kind of crawler to generate a list of urls that are found when crawling your main page and all successive pages in your domain.